# MapView.visibleAnnotations doesn't include MGLPolygon

Tags: annotations, visibility, mapbox

I'm not sure if this is a bug of not.

When I'm displaying a map with a polygon on it and it's completely visible on screen it won't appear in the list of visibleAnnotations despite being returned in the annotations list.

I'm assuming this is a bug? or is there some rationale behind this?

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: I'm seeing this too with no remedy in sight. Also `didSelect` and `visibleAnnotationsInRect` are clueless as to the polygon's existence.

Answer (score 0):

Raised a bug in MapBox and they've eventually fixed this.